# Como obtener numero de filas y columnas de una matriz

Tags: java, array

mi pregunta es la siguiente, **quiero obtener el numero de filas y columnas de mi matriz**, para imprimir su contenido en pantalla, pero en el for **no** quiero colocar i < (numero de elementos que le coloque), quisiera algo como
i < filas.length

```
int numeros[][] = new int [2][3];

    numeros[0][0] = 100;
    numeros[0][1] = 200;
    numeros[0][2] = 300;

    numeros[1][0] = 400;
    numeros[1][1] = 500;
    numeros[1][2] = 600;

    for (int f = 0; f < 2 <=(**Aqui es donde me refiero**); f++) {

        for (int c = 0; c < 3 <=(**Aqui es donde me refiero**); c++) {

            System.out.print(numeros[f][c] + " ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
int numeros[][] = new int [2][3];

numeros[0][0] = 100;
numeros[0][1] = 200;
numeros[0][2] = 300;

numeros[1][0] = 400;
numeros[1][1] = 500;
numeros[1][2] = 600;

for (int f = 0; f < numeros.length; f++) {

   for (int c = 0; c < numeros[f].length; c++) {

       System.out.print(numeros[f][c] + " ");

   }

   System.out.println();
}
```

`numeros.length` almacena la cantidad de filas de la matriz y `numeros[f].length` cuando `f` vale cero accedemos a la cantidad de elementos de la fila cero y así sucesivamente para cada valor de `f`

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, en java al definir una matriz como la que has definido, siempre se crea una matriz de [filas]x[columnas] esto se hace por temas de rendimiento en cache, de esta manera tu programa es mas eficiente al traerse las filas en bloques contiguos (columnas pertenecientes a dicha fila) que es lo que vas a recorrer.

> Para obtener las filas solo te hace falta: `numeros.length`
>
> Para obtener el número de columnas perteneciente a dicha fila:
>   `numeros[i].length`

Ejemplo:

```
int numeros[][] = new int [2][3];

numeros[0][0] = 100;
numeros[0][1] = 200;
numeros[0][2] = 300;

numeros[1][0] = 400;
numeros[1][1] = 500;
numeros[1][2] = 600;

System.out.print("Numero de filas: "+numeros.length);
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
   System.out.print("Fila "+ i + " contiene :" + numeros[i].length + "columnas");
}
```

Nota: Has inicializado los valores de tu matriz en su totalidad, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que si no inicializas algún valor este será inicializado a 0 por defecto, esto es importante ya que si ten interesa saber cuantos campos de la matriz han rellenado realmente, tendrás que hacer una comparación con 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo mismo buscaba espero aun te sirva o para alguien mas, no encontré solución así que utilice la lógica con prueba y error te dejo mi solución es muy fácil:

```
int matriz[][]=new int[2][3];

    System.out.println(matriz.length);//filas
    System.out.println(matriz[0].length);//columnas
```

Comment: Una explicación ayudaría mucho a mejorar tu aporte, checa [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Y 5 años después...

¿No se te ocurrió que lo que deseas no es funcional en términos de rendimiento?
En el loop interno estas pidiendo la medida de la fila, esto lo realizara *i* veces.

Imagina este escenario:

```
int array[][] = new int [500][500];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.print("array["+i+"]"+"["+j+"] "+array[i][j] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Ahora otro código que hace lo mismo:

```
int array[][] = new int [500][500];
int fil= array.length;
int col= array[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
          System.out.print("array["+i+"]"+"["+j+"] "+array[i][j] + " ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Solo verificas la dimensión de la matriz una vez, y luego recorres.

Comment: Asumes que todas las columnas tienen el mismo length. Hace 5 años estaba aprendiendo a programar apenas...

Comment: Hola,  bien, estoy aprendiendo ahora tambien.
No conocia matrices con columnas de diferentes length.